# Angular 17 button (click) event not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a button that should call a function fun() . For some reason, the event is not working at all. Here is the code: TS File:

```
  fun(): void {
    this.test = 'You are my hero!';
    alert('hello')
  }
```

And the HTML:

```
<button type="button" (click)="fun()">Click me!</button>
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong Please help me.

Comment: Hi, honas, did you declare the "fun" function & "test" property inside a @Component ?, Which is the error is giving "DevTools(F12)" > "Console" ?

Comment: Yes, I have declared it but it doesn't work. I am using version 17 of angular Thank you

Comment: "but it doesn't work" is not very helpful. You have to provide us with actual error messages and fully working (minimal) code. What you have posted should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine. If you have trouble working refer the working stackblitz below.

**Check this working code sample:**

> **Please find the working stackblitz [here](https://angular-bfjiyg-jdng4j.stackblitz.io)**.

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  test: string;
  count: number = 0;


  fun(): void {
    this.test = 'You are my hero!';
    this.count++;
    alert('Test message :'+this.test+' Count :'+this.count);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" (click)="fun()">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This should just be a comment, it is not answering a question, it is just giving an example without explaining what the problem was.

Comment: But don't you think That it needs appreciation at least for the reproducible code effort that the person invested in?

Comment: No, I don't. There's no answer here. I can produce a link for a working event handler by just searching.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out,

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
  content: string = "";
  count: number = 0;
  
  setMessage1 () {
    this.content = 'This is message # 1';
  }
}
```

Button click

```
<button (click)="setMessage1()">
Set Message # 1
</button>
```

Comment: This is an example that doesn't explain what the OP's problem was. How does this help the OP understand what they had wrong?

Comment: @RuanMendes but this is the way that is doing.

Comment: thank you very much but not working because i use angular version 17 your way is not working

Comment: @TechGuy I'm not sure what you mean; what are you teaching the OP here? What is different between what you posted and what the OP did? Answers that say "try this out" are usually better as a comment, in this case probably [as a link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/egka51?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)